# Python 2.7 script no longer showing colours in console

Tags: python, python-2.7

It was working just yesterday and I haven't changed anything.

This is what was working before:

```
def printOutput(col,ostr):
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    BLUE = '\033[94m'
    GREEN = '\033[92m'
    RED = '\033[91m'
    YELLOW = '\033[93m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    ostr = str(ostr)
    if(col=='RED'):
          print(RED + ostr + ENDC)
    elif(col=='GREEN'):
      print(GREEN + ostr + ENDC)
    elif(col=='BLUE'):
          print(BLUE + ostr + ENDC)
    elif(col=='YELLOW'):
          print(YELLOW + ostr + ENDC)
    else:
          print(ostr)
```

Comment: Works fine for me in `2.7.10` and `3.6` in Bash. You're going to have to provide a bit more context.

Comment: What OS are you using and how do you run your script? These special characters to change terminal font color work for default on Linux and Mac OS X, but on Windows they will depend on terminal type and some settings to be enabled.

Comment: Also, tehy might not work if you are running the script inside an IDE Python console, ike Pycharm or other.

Comment: No IDE, as soon as i did a windows update it stopped working but works fine on my MAC.